# How to request user permission for html5 geolocation api in web apps?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, geolocation

I have this code to use html5 geolocation

```
    this.getCurrentLocation = function(callback) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
                callback({
                    'lat' : pos.coords.latitude,
                    'lng' : pos.coords.longitude        
                });
            }, function (error) {
                switch(error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert("Could not get your location. User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert("Could not get your location. Location information is unavailable.");
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("Could not get your location. The request to get user location timed out.");
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        alert("Could not get your location. An unknown error occurred.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Could not get your location. An unknown error occurred.");
                }
                callback(null);
            }, {
                maximumAge: 500000, 
                enableHighAccuracy:true, 
                timeout: 6000
            });
        }
    };
```

I'm testing it on my chrome browser on android phone. But it right away goes to saying user denied permission. It doesn't even ask if I want to allow it. How can I get it to request permission. I have in the site settings, that the location should be asked for permission too.

It works if I try on a desktop.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not done via HTML or JavaScript (and that's a good thing). It must be done via the user's app settings. Otherwise, developers would just be able to code acceptance of the use of location services into their apps, bypassing the user's wishes.

Comment: But in my app settings, on google chrome, it says to ask first. The issue is the website is not even asking.

Comment: Turn that setting off and then on again to reset it. Once the app asks you and gets a response, it won't ask again.

Comment: I tried that but it still goes into user denied permission.

Comment: It has to be a device/user-agent setting. This cannot be determined via code. Try it on another device.

Comment: What do you mean it has to be a device/user-agent setting?

Comment: I mean that allowing or not allowing location services is handled by the device that the page is being consumed in. That could be a browser for a desktop machine or an app on a mobile device. It's not controlled via code.

Comment: I fixed it by making it `HTTPS`. Chrome on android just doesn't work for geolocation unless its secure connection.

Comment: @omega That's good that you got your fix. As I did say, this is not something that is handled through code. It's about the user-agent.